# Git merge commits

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm new to git (and enjoying it a lot!). While developing in a new branch, I kept committing the various development 'states' of my application. Now I have to check it in for review but didn't want everything to go in different commits (different comments and ids).

How can I do a push of all changes as if it was the first time?

Comment: @Alex it's fine to close this one (4 years after?) but mine's date is a month older, slightly unfair :)

Comment: @Alex sounds good to me :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

allows you to interactively select which of the 5 last commits to join into one; off the top of my head it opens the editor with something like this

```
pick xxxx commit1
pick xxxx commit2
pick xxxx commit3
pick xxxx commit4
pick xxxx commit5
```

you change this into

```
pick xxxx commit1
squash xxxx commit2
squash xxxx commit3
squash xxxx commit4
pick xxxx commit5
```

which results in two commits being left: first one that has combined commits 1 - 4, and commit 5 (the newest one) which is left alone

Comment: You have the order backwards — the commits are listed oldest-first.

Comment: @jleedev +1 you're right, fixed it

Comment: Thanks! :) I actually soft reset to the commit just before the first commit I made and then did a brand new commit of all changes together but I wasn't happy with my solution. Thanks for this one :)

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a good idea to keep your "micro commits". You can do a diff from the last commit before your feature to the current HEAD to see the entire diff which you can send for review.

Comment: Its more of a scenario-specific thing; usually you will want to rebase and make commits more logical and get rid of "oops!" commits before sending in patches.

Comment: That is true but I don't like squashing the entire week/month of development into a single commit just for the purpose of review. I'm a heavy user of `--amend` myself.

Comment: You're probably both right, as mathepic said, needs to be scenario-specific. In my case I'm sending it for others to review and the 'back-up' commits don't make much sense in there :) Thanks

Comment: Yes. But you don't have to send them a single commit to review. You can send them a range of commits `git diff start end` and ask them to review the entire thing. No?